# How can I convert a row in to one column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I have data like listed below

```
R1= Row1
C1= Column1

R1:  C1     C2    C3     C4    C5      C6     C7          C8     C9     C10
R2: Alpha  Beta  Gamma        Alpha1  Beta1  Gamma1     Alpha2  Beta2  Gamma3
```

I want the data to be like this:

```
R1:  C1       C2      C3      C4    C5      C6     C7     C8
R2: Alpha    Beta    Gamma        
R3: Alpha1   Beta1  Gamma1
R4: Alpha2   Beta2  Gamma2
```

Can you please specify any formula/vba code to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `R2C4` really empty?  Is that the only empty cell in the row?

Comment: No, this is actually indicating the interval every 4th cell in R2 will be empty. For example 123 empty 456 empty 789 empty

Comment: I suggest 1) that you provide a more realistic, useable example of your data; and 2) that you show what you have tried, and where you have run into trouble.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with problems you run into.  I'd suggest using `Power Query` for this. Also suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this will help:**

1. Select the range of data you want to rearrange, including any row or column labels, and press Ctrl+C.(Note: Ensure that you copy the data to do this, since using the Cut command or Ctrl+X won’t work.)
2. Choose a new location in the worksheet where you want to paste the transposed table, ensuring that there is plenty of room to paste your data. The new table that you paste there will entirely overwrite any data / formatting that’s already there.

Right-click over the top-left cell of where you want to paste the transposed table, then choose **Transpose**.

3. After rotating the data successfully, you can delete the original table and the data in the new table will remain intact.

Comment: No Sorry, this is not working. Anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This formula is working for me,
basically I will test some conditions:

```
-Empty cell
-Cell contains only alphabet
-Cell contains number
```

- When cell containing number I use `match function to find the position of the
  first number` that appears, then simply separate left and right,
  finally increat + 1 to get last number.

Here is its formula:

```
B4=IF(B$2="","",IFERROR(LEFT(B$2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(B$2,ROW(A$1:INDEX($A$1:$A$10,LEN(B$2))),1)),0)-1)&ROW(A1)+RIGHT(B$2,LEN(B$2)-MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(1*MID(B$2,ROW(A$1:INDEX($A$1:$A$10,LEN(B$2))),1)),0)+1),B$2&ROW(A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Grid Lock Thanks for your help. I am sorry I am not getting your formula. And please note that C1 and R1 in the questions is just to indicate column1 and Row1. That R1: and C1: is not the part of data.  Question is simple, The data is currently in one row. I want to convert that data into 3 columns. I hope you're getting my question.

Comment: omg, now that I understand your ambiguous question, you didn't say convert these columns into rows, I think you need to number increase each row, which is a waste of my time!

Comment: I am sorry for that, actually I mentioned that in the heading. Anyways, thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX` function can help you:

```
=INDEX($1:$1,1,COLUMN()+(ROW(A5)-5)*4)
```

Part of formula `(ROW(A5)-5)` depends on the position of the result - if the result starts with the first row then it should be changed to `(ROW(A1)-1)`

[image]